# How can I move position of HERE maps info bubble tail?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am trying to replace the Google Maps API with the HERE maps API (3.1) in a couple applications of mine. One thing I am struggling with is positioning info bubbles. I have figured out how to have the info bubble tail anchored to the top of the marker icon instead of the bottom by using a CSS snippet such as (adjust pixel value based on size of icon image used):

```
.H_ib {margin-top:-38px;}
```

This works great. Now I am struggling with making it so that the info bubble tail is in the middle of the bubble and not on the right side.

Here is what it currently looks like:

Current behavior:

[image: current behavior]

And here is what I would like to achieve (screenshot is of Google Maps which defaults to how I would like to make HERE work):

Desired behavior:

[image: desired behavior]

I've tried repositioning with CSS but then the tail is not anchored to the marker icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin-right` in `.H_ib_body` will adjust the position of bubble info body.

for example:

```
.H_ib_body {margin-right: -3em;}
```